# How to write the EXIF data intoa saved image file in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, exif

I was trying to re save the image file if the orientation was not right. But the issue is when i  try to rotate an image and overwrite it to the same file, it works fine but the EXIF informations are not being saved in the overwritten file.

But i want to save all the EXIF data in the new overwritten image as same as the old one except the orientation value. Please help. thanks.

Comment: can we see some of your code?

Comment: For features that are not supported out of the box of CF, look for an easy-to-use Java library and utilize it from CF is generally a good idea.